# How to retrieve accelerations from ode

Tags: matlab, size, ode

As the title says I'd like to know how to retrieve the 2nd order derivative from a Matlab ode.
The system i'm trying to simulate is described by 12 1st order differential equations.

Let's explain:

```
...

[T,Y] = ode113(@sixdofsolver,time,Y0,options,settings);
```

T = 1700x1 vector

Y = 1700x12 matrix

Now if i do:

```
[dY] = sixdofsolver(T,Y,settings)
```

dY = 12x1 vector

I'd have expected to have a same-size matrix like Y.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Your integration function `sixdofsolver` is likely designed first for used by Matlab's ODE solvers. These functions evaluate the function at one point in time (and a single state value) rather than across a range of times.

You either need to rewrite your `sixdofsolver` function so that it can handle more than a single time or your need to create a new function based on it that does that. In other words you need to vectorize the integration function. You probably have variable like `y(1)`, `y(2)`, ..., y(12)`. Well, now the input state vector is a matrix so you need to use something like`y(:,1)`,`y(:,2)`, ..., y(:,12)`. You may need to do other things like switch to element-wise operators. I can't help you more from what you've provided.

Comment: Thanks. That's just what I was worried about... (The sixdofsolver is quite long and complex. Anyway I'll try to manage how to rewrite and If i would need help I'll post here the code.) Thanks.